# Can Hacker break the integrity of the data in UDP protocol?

Tags: integrity, udp

Comparing the checksum received in the UDP segment with the checksum calculated in the data helps UDP determine the integrity of the data. Is there a case where the **Hacker changes both the corresponding binary value of the data and the checksum in the UDP segment** to fool that the data sent has never been changed? Is there any solution if that happens?

Answer (score 1):

IP, UDP, TCP etc do not provide any kind of protection against an attacker changing the traffic and detecting such a change. This is instead provided by protocols like TLS, DTLS, QUIC, IPSec ... which provide cryptographic integrity protection, for example using [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC).

Note that this kind of integrity protection also needs some kind of secret known to the intended communication peer but unknown to the attacker, because otherwise the attacker could just modify the content and apply the cryptographic integrity protection to the modified content.